# how to load large hdt files using jena

Tags: rdf, jena, dbpedia

I am working on DBPedia hdt file which its size is 35GB I tried to load this file to model using HDTManager and the code is as below

```
 HDT hdt = null;
            
            try {
                hdt = HDTManager.mapIndexedHDT("src/dbpedia2016-10.hdt", null);
                HDTManager.loadHDT("src/dbpedia2016-10.hdt", null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HDTGraph graph = new HDTGraph(hdt,true);
            Model model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(graph);
```

but I got an error on this line

```
hdt = HDTManager.mapIndexedHDT("src/dbpedia2016-10.hdt", null);
```

the error is size exceed as illustrated below

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:941)
    at org.rdfhdt.hdt.dictionary.impl.section.PFCDictionarySectionMap.<init>(PFCDictionarySectionMap.java:138)
    at org.rdfhdt.hdt.dictionary.impl.section.DictionarySectionFactory.loadFrom(DictionarySectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.rdfhdt.hdt.dictionary.impl.FourSectionDictionary.mapFromFile(FourSectionDictionary.java:134)
    at org.rdfhdt.hdt.hdt.impl.HDTImpl.mapFromHDT(HDTImpl.java:279)
    at org.rdfhdt.hdt.hdt.HDTManagerImpl.doMapIndexedHDT(HDTManagerImpl.java:66)
    at org.rdfhdt.hdt.hdt.HDTManager.mapIndexedHDT(HDTManager.java:148)
    at app.Gui.generateFeatureSet(Gui.java:574)
    at app.Gui$4.actionPerformed(Gui.java:274)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

how to solve the file exceed issue in this case. Is there an other way to deal with such a large file
I appreciate your help.
thanks.

Comment: This is happening before any Jena code. Specifically, the HDT code is trying to create a memory mapped segment of size more then 2G. (The line number aligns with JDK11 - the 2G limit is part of the NIO API so it is not version specific.)

Comment: thank you for your comment, so how can I extend this limit to allow loading big file like this file which is 35GB

Comment: I don't know the details of HDT very well but browsing the code it seems that  FCDictionarySectionMap passes a size >2G to the JDK runtime because there is a block in the file that is >2G. It is not to do with your code; there may be an HDT option to run in a different mode. Some of the java code has classes that work around this limitation. It has been reported before: https://github.com/rdfhdt/hdt-java/issues/93 and I've added a comment to the issue.

Comment: My guess is that the file has been written by the C++ version of HDT and does not have this java specific limit. If this is true, unpacking with the C++ and repacking with the java version may work (I haven't tried). Hopefully, a response to issues/93 from someone more knowledgeable will provide a solution.